# forwarding multiple messages in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

the problem: when I ^A (multiple messages get selected) and press 'forward' - Outlook wants to send all of them as 1 message. however, i need to send each message individually, meaning w/o any grouping.

how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Quick Step and click that step for each mail (or try to have them all selected).

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W29zY7Hb4Q0) for an explanation how to do it.

[image]